Airflow - login next query param does not match the base_url #
I deployed my airflow application behind a Microsoft application gateway. I updated the base_url to match the public IP provided by the application gateway, for example, 1.2.3.4.
However, when I try to access the login page, the "next" query parameter refers to the internal IP of the machine (for example, 192.0.0.0) instead of the public IP of the Application Gateway.
So for instance, I have this value as base_url
BASE_URL=http://1.2.3.4/airflow

When see the login page the URL looks like this:
http://1.2.3.4/airflow/login/?next=http%3A%2F%2F192.0.0.0%2Fairflow%2Fhome

I was expecting to see something like this:
http://1.2.3.4/airflow/login/?next=http%3A%2F%2F1.2.3.4%2Fairflow%2Fhome

Is there some additional configuration that I have to set?
NOTE: i'm not using kubernetes, but plain virtual machines
aiflow 2.6.2

If the "next" query parameter in your Airflow application is referencing the internal IP instead of the public IP provided by the Application Gateway, you can resolve this by setting the X-Forwarded-Host header in your Application Gateway configuration. @Mattia

do u know where i can find that configuration in the portal UI? @VinayB

Navigate to your Application Gateway: In the Azure portal, go to your Application Gateway resource.
Settings > Listeners: Under the "Settings" section, click on "Listeners."
HTTP Settings: Click on the HTTP settings associated with your listener.
Custom Headers: In the HTTP settings, scroll down to the "Custom headers" section.
Add Header: Add a new custom header with the name X-Forwarded-Host and set the value to your public IP or DNS name. @Mattia
